# How to set all chosen directives true inside one form

Tags: angularjs

I have such situation:

```html
<form name="test" >
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <input ng-model="field.value"  my-directive>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have 3 fields to validate and I have a rule:
If only one of 3 fields have a value then true, else false.

So, when I have all fields with numbers and then delete 2 fields and left one field with number I have to make all other fields set true, but they are false, how to do it correctly?

```js
function myDirective() {

    function checkChosenField(fields) {

      var obj = {};

      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {


          if (ctrl.$name === "one" || ctrl.$name === "two" || ctrl.$name === "three") {
            ctrl.$validators.myDirective = function(viewValue) {
              obj[ctrl.$name] = viewValue;

              var rule = // rule is correct
                if (rule) {


                  // I have to set other fields ttue manualy, 'couse they still have false validation value
                  ctrl.$setValidity('one', true); // don't need, 'couse returning true 
                  ctrl.$setValidity('two', true); // doesn't work
                  ctrl.$setValidity('three', true);  // doesn't work
                  console.log('CTRL', ctrl);

                  return true; // returning true only for current directive
                } else {

                  return false;
                }
            }

          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So, if to look inside form it contains $error where I can see my-directive, as I understand I have to set it globaly true;